# SSRS Application - Expression to display values in a hidden parameter

Tags: parameters, expression, ssrs-2012

I have created a parameter in a drill down report. This parameter is hidden but I created it for the purposes of the drill down from the main report. However when you drill down, I want a box at the top of the report, to show the values in the hidden parameter.

So, if you are viewing all the sales made for the month of September, globally, but you want to view all the sales made for product A, you double click product A, then it goes into your drill down report. In your drill down report, you see all the sales made for product A and all the specific countries that made sales for that product in the month of September.

In the drill down report the country parameter is hidden, but I was a text box to display the countries we are looking at the sales data for.

What expression can I use?

Comment: What application are you using?  Please include that in your question title!

Comment: I'm using ssrs application

Comment: Use either    `=Parameters!myParameterName.Value` or `=Parameters!myParameterName.Label`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do expression level evaluation but keep in mind this will put load on the reporting server. Since you are pulling everything at the drill down level adding country will not affect your performance (Worse case create a nci on sql side). Just a suggestion. Finally, may want to try your user(s) most rendered format be excel, pdf etc. to make sure expression displays correctly as you are only viewing on the report server or bids. While actual user will view in the format requested.